# jquery slider detect end of scroll?

Tags: jquery, slider

How will I know if jquery slider is at the end of the scroll?

I'll call an ajax function to load a page when I reach it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do a slide, you can pass in a function to be called after the animation is over.

```
$('#myEl').slideDown(function(){
    alert('Animation complete!');
});
```